# How to change the x/y/z properties of a QItemDelegate, without using QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm converting a piece of code I initially made with QML, to a QML-less application; one of the QML components is a GridView, which features a 'delegate' Item to render the content of the model provided to the GridView. In the end, it shows a grid with several widgets, organized like this
xxxxxxxxxxx
x 1 2 3 4 x
x 5 6 7 8 x
xxxxxxxxxxx
My goal is to increase the size and center the widget 'X' when it's pressed; then to come back to the initial position when it's pressed again (kind of zoom in/out).
QML allows to change the x/y/z properties of a delegate, like so:

```
GridView {
    id: monitorDivisionsGrid
    model: myModel
    cellWidth: width/maxItemsPerLine
    cellHeight: height/maxItemsPerColumn
    interactive: count > (maxItemsPerLine * maxItemsPerColumn)
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    delegate: Item {
        property bool hasIndex: monitorDivisionsGrid.currentIndex == index
        width: lastFocused >= 0 && hasIndex ? GridView.view.cellWidth*1.5 : GridView.view.cellWidth
        height: lastFocused >= 0 && hasIndex ? GridView.view.cellHeight*1.5 : GridView.view.cellHeight

        z: lastFocused >= 0 && hasIndex ? 2 : 1
        x: {
            if (lastFocused >= 0 && hasIndex)
                return monitorDivisionsGrid.x + (monitorDivisionsGrid.width - width)/2 // centered
            else
                return monitorDivisionsGrid.x + index%maxItemsPerLine * GridView.view.cellWidth
        }
        y: {
            if (lastFocused >= 0 && hasIndex)
                return monitorDivisionsGrid.y + (monitorDivisionsGrid.height - height)/2 // centered
            else {
                return monitorDivisionsGrid.y + Math.floor((index/maxItemsPerLine) % maxItemsPerLine) * GridView.view.cellHeight
            }
        }
```

I don't know how i can achieve this without QML, using only QtWidget-approach.

To convert this to a QML-less application, I use a custom delegate 'MyCustomDelegate' which inherits from QItemDelegate, and overload the 'paint' and 'sizeHint' methods. Overloading the sizeHint allows the increase/decrease of the currently selected item, but I cannot find any way to move 'MyCustomDelegate' !

```
void MyCustomDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
```

For instance, since 'option' is const, it's not possible to call some code like

```
option.rect.moveTo(newX,newY).
```

Moreover there's no 'positionHint' method provided with QItemDelegate...
And I have no idea how to act upon 'z' property...

Any help appreciated ;o)

Comment: You can maybe copy `option` (`QStyleOptionViewItem` has a copy constructor) and do what you wish with the copy.

Comment: i tried to achieve this copy, like this: `QStyleOptionViewItem opt = setOptions(index, option);` then i tried to call `opt.rect.moveTo(newX, newY)`; but the delegate is not translated to QPoint(newX,newY).. i think i can't operate on option.rect (which is actually the rectangle that natively bears the delegate rendering) from within the "paint" method :o(

Comment: That's not a simple call to the copy constructor... anyway, how do you use `opt` in your code?

Comment: yes you're right, i forgot to mention that i initially tried with the strict copy ctor, but no success neither.. as i said, i'm using opt like this `opt.rect.moveTo`, in order to "move" the element in its container

Comment: as i said, from within the paint method, which i override from QItemDelegate in my own delegate implementation, i use this code to move the option.rect : `opt.rect.moveTo(42,42);`; but copying "option" to "opt" has no effect on the movement

Comment: If all you do is change `opt.rect` then discard `opt` without ever using it, it is no wonder your delegate does not move.....

Comment: OK, then my question is : is it possible to act on x y z from within the overriden paint method of a delegate ? So as to move the element at a given index ?

Comment: While it is possible to do everything in QML in C++, and, in fact, QML is written in C++, the counter-argument is why would you want to? The reason why QML/C++ works is it achieves a balance between business application logic and native code to increase productivity, maintainability, and reliability. Whilst you can do everything in C++, you're heading towards a path of long-term pain. Hence my question "why would you want to?".

Comment: in addition to above comments, if zoom in/out is the only matter, why not taking advantage of letting that kind of things to the layout system instead of changing delegate item's x,y properties?

Comment: @StephenQuan that's the expectation from the GUI I'm designing.. on screen I have a grid of several items, displayed with a QListView (because the number of elements may increase); when the user hits one element, it's zoomed in and "translated" to the center of the QListView, in order to have a better readability of the contents. I first coded in QML and it worked like a charm, but for many reasons I know need to do it without QML..

Comment: @dynerp as far as I know the QListview manages the layout of its elements according to the flow direction, the wrapping, and the sizeHint of the elements; what do you mean with "letting this to the layout system" ?

Comment: @Fred I mean it is not a good practice to override x, y properties in delegates. You'll override default layout behavior and position them according to the new values you set. Best choice would be anchoring them properly in order to "let the layout system handle the resizing for you"

Comment: yes i agree, but my need is actually to "unanchor" the element, to extract it from the automatic layout.. I have the feeling there's no solution using delegates. I'm now working on a turnaround : do not use listview/delegate, but instead use a QGridLayout with manual positioning. Seems to answer my need so far. Thank you all.

Comment: I finally gave up the use of a GridLayout to set the position of my model's elements : indeed, i don't know the amount of elements, therefore in some cases this amount will cause my display to be too small, and I'll need to scroll, which is natively achieved by a QListView ... I think it's worth fixing my issue with the translation of the focused elements within the QListView, in order to fully leverage its usage..